# How can I pass selector ID's as variables to JQuery through casperjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, casperjs

I'm writing a scraper in casperjs and I'm trying to select a value from a dropdown list. The best way I've found to do this so far is to use JQuery. But, if I pass the ID of the selector as a variable, the selector is not updated where, if I pass it as a string, the selector is update perfectly.

Works:

```
var specialtySelector = '#specialitydiv';
casper.evaluate(function () {
  $('#specialitydiv').find('select').val('238').change();
});
```

Fails:

```
var specialtySelector = '#specialitydiv';
casper.evaluate(function () {
  $(specialtySelector).find('select').val('238').change();
});
```

Can anyone explain why passing specialtySelector would fail when passing the selector as a string succeeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that CasperJS' `evaluate()` is running independently of the rest of the script. To fix this, you need to pass along any variables that you want to use inside of the `evaluate()`.

```js
var specialtySelector = '#specialitydiv';
casper.evaluate(function(sel) {
  $(sel).find('select').val('238').change();
}, specialtySelector);
```

The reason why the first example works is because you aren't actually using any variables that aren't available to the `evaluate()` call.